# Postgredb in conda environment or keep standalone

Tags: python, postgresql, conda, anaconda3

I am looking for some guidance. I have Anaconda installed to manage my python packages and environments. I see that you can install postgres in the package manager.
Am I best to install postgres in the conda environment or install standalone. I am on Windows.

I see that if I install postgres separately I get pgadmin graphical interface. This could be very helpful for me.

I cannot see a graphical interface when postgres is installed via conda.

If I install standalone postgres do I have delete all the conda installed postgres instances.

Many thanks.

Comment: conda always installs the CLI version of everything so you won't find that. about your question, it's better to install it in a separate environment so you can do that.

Comment: If you say you installed postgres in the anaconda package manager, i think you might be referring to [this package](https://pypi.org/project/postgres/) which is an abstraction of psycopg2, a driver for postgres, and not the actual database itself. So yes, install postgres standalone and use a connector (i prefer the actual psycopg2 package) in your anaconda project afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ameya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17637655/ameya) and [mnikley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12892026/mnikley) helped in the comments ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72862959/postgredb-in-conda-environment-or-keep-standalone/72878995#comment128698135_72862959), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72862959/postgredb-in-conda-environment-or-keep-standalone/72878995#comment128700450_72862959))

I have kept my postgres db separate and I am using the psycopg2 package as the connector. There is a package that includes postgres as I found out when I installed postgres stand alone as it could not use port 5432. I uninstalled the posrgres package from within conda and everything works perfectly.